# WICConvertBitmapSource() gives link error

Tags: c++, wic

I was trying to encode an image using WIC.
and i made simple dll (to encode/decode) and reffered it from another aplication.

I added `my_bitmap_converter()` to do a convertion intended to use `WICConvertBitmapSource()` but it gives me a link error. here is my work

```
int my_bitmap_converter
(
    REFWICPixelFormatGUID dstPixelFormt, 
    IWICBitmapSource* piBitmapSource, 
    IWICBitmapSource** ppiBitmapDst
)
{
    IWICBitmapSource* piScr = piBitmapSource;
    IWICBitmapSource** ppiDst = ppiBitmapDst;

    hr = WICConvertBitmapSource
        (
        dstPixelFormt,//GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat, 
        piScr,
        ppiDst
        );
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        piScr->Release();
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

how can i get rid of this error

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _WICConvertBitmapSource@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl my_bitmap_converter(struct _GUID const &,struct IWICBitmapSource
>   *,struct IWICBitmapSource * *)" (?my_bitmap_converter@@YAHABU_GUID@@PAUIWICBitmapSource@@PAPAU2@@Z)

---wincodec.h---

```
HRESULT WINAPI WICConvertBitmapSource(
     _In_ REFWICPixelFormatGUID dstFormat, // Destination pixel format
     _In_reads_(1) IWICBitmapSource  *pISrc,    // Source bitmap
     _Outptr_result_buffer_(1) IWICBitmapSource **ppIDst   // Destination bitmap, a copy or addrefed source
     );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you referred [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719819(v=vs.85).aspx), you may realize that "Link library name is "windowscodecs.lib" instead of "wincodec.lib" in Windows SDK 7.0 "

maybe you are using SDK 7.0 or later. if it is, try adding windowscodecs.lib as an additional dependencies.

Comment: what version were you using.

Comment: I have installed several versions (6 to 8) but acording to the regedit, current version is 6. but i included windowscodecs.lib anyway. that stop the errer when i call that function in a nother function above error came up again.